# Set height of toolbar using AutoLayout and support orientation

Tags: iphone, ios6, autolayout

I want to set the height of Toolbar equal to navigation bar height, and toolbar height should change on changing orientation as Navigation bar does.
I tried this 
`NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint     constraintWithItem:reportingToolbar   
                                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight      
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual         
                                toItem:self.navigationController.navigationBar    
                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight

multiplier:1.0f

constant:0.0f];`

[self.parentViewController.navigationController.view addConstraints:@[heightConstraint]];

Is there anything wrong in above code. This code crashes saying "views out of the tree".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case what you want is to set the relative object as nil, and simply set the constant.

Any view listed in your constraint must be at or below the view you add the constraint to in the view hierarchy.

Comment: Please post the exact error message text and the code you are using. Is your view appearing on the screen at all?